# AmChart - addTitle not defined

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm trying to build some charts using AmCharts, and I need to set the titles dynamically.  According to the docs, each chart should have an addTitle() method:

http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart

```
addTitle(text, size, color, alpha, bold)
text - text of a title size - font size color - title color alpha - title opacity bold - boolean value indicating if title should be bold.
Adds title to the top of the chart. Pie, Radar positions are updated so that they won't overlap. Plot area of Serial/XY chart is also updated unless autoMargins property is set to false. You can add any number of titles - each of them will be placed in a new line. To remove titles, simply clear titles array: chart.titles = []; and call chart.validateNow() method.
```

I can see no such method. I'm creating the chart using AmCharts.makeChart(), passing a div and a chart definition object:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart($chartDiv[0], chartDefinition);
```

When I examine my chart object, I can see the array of titles I've included in my chartDefinition, but there's no addTitle() method defined on it.

Answer (score 0):

As i have to rights to comment atm, i'm posting this as answer.
I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z6LktLm3/9/) and tried to reproduce your problem. As you can see everything is working fine. (Even with only one parameter in `addTitle`)
Maybe you could post your code, if your problem is still occuring?